# Does the use of 予 such as in 猶予 to mean "in advance" have any precedent in Chinese?

Tags: chinese

There are a lot of Japanese words that use the morpheme よ, written 予, to mean "in advance". This clearly looks like a loan from Chinese, but I do not know of any examples of Chinese words or texts that use 予 in such a way.

Are there any examples of the usage of 予 to mean "in advance" in Chinese? If there are, it must have been a rather rare usage. What would explain the large number of Japanese words that use it in this way?

Answer (score 4):

予 in Japanese is also a simplified version of 豫. 猶予 corresponds to Mandarin 犹豫.

http://ja.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E4%BA%88

Answer (score 1):

In modern traditional Chinese, you can use "預約(**appointment** in advance)" and "予約" as compatible writing.  予 is much easier than 預 in writing form. Therefore,    "予" is the simplification written form of "in advance" and you have to combine two kanji to present more meaning.  [Ref: wiktionary 予約](https://ja.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E4%BA%88%E7%B4%84)